# How to add custom text with node reference autocomple value?

Tags: nodes, ajax

i stucked in a very serious problem, i want to add my custom text with node reference target value, i already spent three days to figure out whats wrong, so finally after spending my 3 days on it to figure out whats wrong is going on i am here

here is my code :
in node.module

```
function node_field_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  global $user;
  if($form_id=='article-node-form'){
    $form['field_related_nodes']['und'][0]['target_id']['#autocomplete_path']= "somik"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the callback code for the path you've defined at 'somik'? Also you're missing a semi-colon at the end of that line, probably resulting in a white screen

Comment: I've just re-read that...your code shouldn't be in the node module it should be in a custom module, and you need to implement the `form_alter()` hook based on a naming convention. I'd highly recommend you go through the [module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) to become familiar with writing code for Drupal, I think you're missing a lot of the key concepts at the moment

Comment: @clive i badly need your help here, there is some problem in my development server so cant check whether my code is correct or not will you please have alook last comment of mine in ths page http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72641/need-to-show-user-firstname-and-lastname-in-search-result-page