# need to show user firstname and lastname in search result page

Tags: users

I'm very new in drupal, and I have a custom user module where I need to show the user's first name and last name in the search result page. I used some of my code which is throwing a fatal error.

What is wrong with the code I am using?

```
function somik_user_byline($uid) {
  $cache = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
  if (isset($cache[$uid])) {
    return $cache[$uid];
  }

  $account = user_load($uid);
  $byline = $account->name;

  $first_name = somik_user_profile_field_value($uid, 'field_firstname');
  $last_name = somik_user_profile_field_value($uid, 'field_lastname');

  if ($first_name && $last_name) {
    $byline = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;
  }

  $cache[$uid] = $byline;

  return $byline;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by " in search result page"? Do you mean for each search result or just once on the page somewhere (in which case, where on the page)? - Also, where are you calling the somik_user_byline() function from?

Comment: i) After each node in search result page, i want to show its user's full name <br/>
ii) In search result page (blocked areas)<br/>
<br/>
`
 <div class="search-snippet-info">
    <?php if ($snippet): ?>
      <p class="search-snippet"<?php print <br/>$content_attributes; ?>><?php print $snippet; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($info): ?>
 <p class="search-info">
<?php
    **bold**print drupal_render(somik_user_byline($user->uid))**bold** &nbsp .$info_split['date'];
?> 
</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</li>
code`

Comment: Try without the drupal_render() part around your function call. - Just: print somik_user_byline($user->uid)

Comment: do i use simple
<?php print somik_user_byline($user->uid) &nbsp; $info_split['date']; ?>

Comment: <?php print somik_user_byline($user->uid) . '&nbsp;' . $info_split['date']; ?>

Comment: Thanks one more thing sir,how to use theme_preprocess functions to add or alter any additional theme variables any good referal site??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your error replace:

```
<?php print drupal_render(somik_user_byline($user->uid)) &nbsp .$info_split['date']; ?>
```

with

```
<?php print somik_user_byline($user->uid) . '&nbsp;' . $info_split['date']; ?>
```

For preprocessing you would use:

```
/**
 * Process variables for the search result template.
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  // Change variables here.
}
```

There is some more info here http://drupal.org/node/223430
It also links to some other useful related pages.

You need to clear the drupal cache when you add or remove a preprocess function.

**Edit:**

For your "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context"

It is because of this part:

```
if (!empty(somik_user_byline($user->uid))) {
  $info['user'] = somik_user_byline($user->uid);
}
```

Because you can't pass a function call into the empty() function like that. You need to give it a variable.

Because your somik_user_byline() function is always returning a string you can do this:

```
if ($name = somik_user_byline($user->uid)) {
  $info['user'] = name;
}
```

You can go even further than that still.
Because your function always returns a non-empty string, you can just do this:

```
$info['user'] = somik_user_byline($user->uid);
```

Also, for it to be available in the template you have to add it to the $variables array.

For example, you are setting $info but to have it in the template you have to do

```
$variables['info'] = $info;
```

at the end and then $info will be available in your template file.

Also, in this case, $info is already full of other information to remember that this will overwrite whatever was alredy in $info from other modules.

If you want to keep the $info that is already there, but override the $info['user'] and $info['date'] parts, do this:

```
/**
 * Process the variables for search-result.tpl.php
 */
function somik_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  $result = $variables['result'];

  // Override the user part of the info array.
  $variables['info_split']['user'] = somik_user_byline($result['node']->uid);
  // Override the date part of the info array.
  if (!empty($result['date'])) {
    $variables['info_split']['date'] = format_date($result['node']->created, 'short');
  }
  // Re-create the info string with the overridden data.
  $variables['info'] = implode(' - ', $info_split);
}
```

Comment: sir i used this way in preprocess function but still "fatal error"

`function somik_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
if (!empty(somik_user_byline($user->uid))) {
    $info['user'] = somik_user_byline($user->uid);
  }
  if (!empty($result['date'])) {
    $info['date'] = format_date($result['node']->created, 'short');
  }
}`

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: Answer updated with more info regarding your error.

Comment: Sir, i tried to assign this `somik_user_byline($uid)` in `$info['user']` using theme preprocess function, as i explained before `somik_user_byline($uid)` is coming from one of my custom module somik_user.module, so is there any problem that i am using to show under theme preprocess instead of module_name preprocess, Error was same : Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in my directory path on line ...

Comment: What is the line number in the error, and what is the line of code at that line? - As mentioned above, the line   if (!empty(somik_user_byline($user->uid))) { will definitely cause that error message. The code example at the bottom of my answer should work for you, unless the error is in your somik_user_byline() function or in your tempate file or somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks sir your last code works, but i dont know why still its pulling username not full name, i know its very tough to understand with this much explaination, i am trying
Thanks a lot sir

Comment: Call to undefined function somik_user_byline() in directory path on line 293 
 this line: `$variables['info_split']['user'] = somik_user_byline($result['node']->uid);`

Comment: That means there is no function somik_user_byline(), so maybe your custom somik_user module you entioned is not enabled?

Comment: i have one thing to say after this Mr Reuben Turk, "YOU are Genious"
thanks for everything, neva thought if some1 assigned me to do something he might not enabled that particular module...